# Ubuntu 20.04.2 resetted to default settings

Tags: 20.04, settings, default

So Ubuntu 20.04.2 in my machine resetted to default settings after startup. Before startup, I had to do a hard shutdown as the system hanged up and I couldn't do anything.
After startup, all my preferences and pinned applications are removed. Did anybody face this? How can I get back settings?

Comment: Restore your latest backup.